# I am getting some lock format wait while i want to install chrome

Tags: 20.04

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X6nn.png this is the error iam getting

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** It appears that your computer is/was in the process of doing something else (I'd guess updates). Are you always getting this error message, even after rebooting your computer?